# Jquery changing dynamic element name not working in IE7

Tags: dynamic, internet-explorer-7, element, jquery

I have some code which clones a HTML Select element. The cloning works fine.

The cloned elements will have an id={original_element_id}-1

After the element is cloned, in IE7 I am unable to select the element. For example:

Original element:

```
<select name="13">
    <option>Value 1
    <option>Value 2
</select>
```

Cloned Element:

```
<select name="13-1">
    <option>Value 1
    <option>Value 2
</select>
```

I try this:

```
$("[name='13-1']").live('click',function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

This works in Chrome, but in IE7 it doesnt work.

How do I select the dynamically created element in IE7 ?

I am using Jquery 1.4.2, I have tried 1.4.3, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.6.2

Comment: It looks like you have not valid HTML here and not finished selector in jQuery.. use `<option>option1</option>` and in jquery `$('input[name="13-1"]).click(function() {});`.

Comment: The thing is that IE is always VERY picky when it comes to inserting invalid code into the DOM, whereas other browsers are far more forgiving / have better error correction. Make sure you form your code properly and it should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested my version IE7 and working fine, change your script to the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='13-1']").live('click', function() {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/LE9Ed/

**UPDATE**

Dynamic html : http://jsfiddle.net/LE9Ed/1/

Comment: In your jsfiddle example the element isnt cloned/added dynamically. I suspect that this is the cause of the issue in IE

Comment: The .live click event will handle dynamic elements. It was your jquery selector that was incorrect... use $("select[name='13-1']")

Comment: Are you calling your jquery script when document ready? e.g. $(function() { /*code*/ });

Comment: yeah. Does work in Chrome so not sure why IE is giving me issues

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle link of your code. I just want to make sure if everything is fine. IE is very buggy when it comes to invalid structured html etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$orig = $('select');

$orig.clone().attr('name', '13-1').appendTo('body');

$("[name='13-1']").live('click',function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

1. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/B5m6F/5/
2. Also there's a missing bracket where you're using the name attribute

Comment: the missing bracket was a typo in my post, still having issues

Comment: Does my jsfiddle not work for you in IE7? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: strangely I get a JS error - Line: 169, Char:28, Error: Access Denied

Comment: In my fiddle? I you just call the url above in IE7 and change the value in the second dropdown you'll get an alert. IF you hit "Run" in jsfiddle you'll get a js error but I doubt that has anything to do with the example.

Comment: yeah but im using IETester so im that might be the issue

Comment: I wouldn't rely on IE tester. If you're using windows use virtual pc (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) or on Mac either Parallels or VMWare Fusion.